# TextChanged Event in MS Access

Tags: events, ms-access, textchanged

Is there a way in in MS Access to detect a changed TextBox value where the TextBox's controlsource is e.g. `=[txtSubTotal]-[txtDiscount]`?

The TextBox is Locked=No, Enabled=Yes but obviously cannot be directly edited by the user since it is a calculated field.

What I'm looking for is the something like the Winforms TextChanged event but the nearest equivalents in Access appear to be `AfterUpdate` and `Change` and neither of those are firing when my TextBox's value changes.

Currently working in Access 2003, though this may change.

Comment: Currently working in Access 2003 ... but will possibly implement this code across A2K and A2007

Comment: When you say readonly, I assume you are specifically referring to *calculated*.  All calculated controls are read-only, but not all read-only controls are calculated.

Comment: Given that the calculated value will change any time either or both of the fields in the calculation change, why can't you use those two fields to figure out when the calculated value changes?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton i can ... But am I not then maintaining the code in two places? KISS, DRY etc?

Comment: No. Write a single sub/function that does what needs to be done, and call it from both places. That's pretty basic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name update implies, this event will fire when data is updated into the tables.

As there is no update (to the tables) for your calculated control, no after or before update event will fire.

You have to write the event handers for the controls where the data is changed.

Comment: ...or in the form's events, checking the values in the individual fields.

Comment: @awrigley But am I not then maintaining the code in multiple places? KISS, DRY etc?

Comment: No, you would only have it in one place:  the right place.  You need to target the correct event.  When data is modified, you need to run the code that updates the calculated text box.  As David Fenton says, the best place is probably the form events.  DRY is good, but not everything can be dried out.  You risk dying of a self imposed drought that way.  Rather than KISS, in this instance, I would say:  ITLATTS (Its The Logic And The Technology, sir).

Comment: @awrigley ITLS OK, but how is it only in one place? in my example field whose control source is [txtSubTotal]-[txtDiscount], then the subtotal and the discount can both change independently. I've got to monitor both - that's two places (even this actually a greatly simplified version of what I'm grappling with)

Comment: Handle it with the form events, that is only in one place.  But even if you decide to control it with event handlers for each control (for some specific reason) you are still only putting code where it HAS to go.  A calculated control is unaware of the other controls (now that is DRY + Separation of Concerns, encapsulation...) so it simply won't do what you want it to.  You are putting the principles before the implementation of the technology, which will give you grief.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't do it in the form events, because the calculation can be updated in contexts in which the form events don't fire. I'd write a sub/function to do what needs to be done and call it in the AfterUpdate event of both of the controls bound to the fields on which the calculation depends. If there's no AfterUpdate event for either of those now, make like easy on yourself, and write the code as a function, and you can just past it into the event property, e.g., =MyFunction().